# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease' [Error]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I could not find solution of this error. I have searched a lot but none of any answer solve my problem. I have wasted 4 hours on this issue. Kindly give any solution. The error is coming only when i run android project on release mode. I have recently updated android studio 2.3, and also I updated my gradle.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     rx/exceptions/MissingBackpressureException.class

**App Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {


    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ventup"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        signingConfigVtraining {
            keyAlias 'vtraining'
            keyPassword 'test*'
            storeFile file('../keystore/keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'test*'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signingConfigVtraining
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signingConfigVtraining
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-sw600dp']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['lib']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.5.3'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.5.3'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.5.3']
    )
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
    //FloatingGroupExpandableListView
    compile project(path: ':mediaPicker')
    compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.1.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.github.nicolasjafelle:paginggridview:1.0'



    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.diegocarloslima:fgelv:0.1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile project(':crop')
    compile files('libs/KochavaSDK.jar')

//Image compressor
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'



    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.1'

    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4';


    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You are adding twice the rx/exceptions/MissingBackpressureException class

Comment: That's a lot of libraries... I would suggest cutting back or decoupling something. For example. You can don't need Volley and other network libraries. Your Volley is deprecated anyway... You don't need Jackson and Gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude `rxjava` module from `io.reactivex` to avoid including `rxjava` twice :

```
compile('id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4') {
    exclude group: 'io.reactivex', module: 'rxjava'
}
```

Comment: After adding exclude line, I was facing GCOverHead error. So I just add

 dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

lines in android block. now it is working fine.